# Why does Oracle not support an autonumber data type?

Tags: oracle, auto-increment

I know that Oracle implements autonumber functionality using sequences and triggers, but why doesn't it have a built-in autonumber data type as do most relational DBMSs? There are two specific parts to my question:

- I know that sequences with triggers are generally more flexible than what autonumber fields in other DBMSs provide. However, what are the some particularly superior features of Oracle's implementation?
- Considering that autonumber for primary key attributes is such a universal use case, what is the disadvantage of implementing it that keeps Oracle from adding such built-in functionality? After all, they can still keep sequences and triggers with any additional features they might provide.

I know that this question might be difficult, since it is not a "how-to" question but rather a question asking background behind Oracle's design decisions for their DBMS. However, I feel there is much to be learnt in understanding Oracle's thinking in this matter.

Comment: Oracle's design principles seem to be organized around human-oriented facets.  As such, an automated IDENTITY type seems anathema.  Using a sequence allows the designer more fine-grained control over the data presented to the user.  Nonetheless, this question is off-topic since the answers will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: You can use sequences in default values for columns since 12c, so nothing is "keeping Oracle from adding such built-in functionnality".

Comment: @MaxVernon, could you please expound on "Oracle's design principles seem to be organized around human-oriented facets. As such, an automated IDENTITY type seems anathema." Obviously, since IDENTITY has been introduced in 12c, it is not anathema, but I would really like to better understand Oracle's design principles that you refer to here. Actually, the question is not opinion-based if someone could point to a blog or something where Oracle has explained their reasoning. That's what I'm hoping for--that would be a fairly objective answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it does now - Oracle 12c introduced **`IDENTITY`** columns, see:

[Identity Columns in Oracle Database 12c Release 1 (12.1)](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1.php)

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE identity_test_tab (
   id          NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
   description VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

Comment: And it has [`SEQUENCE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm) since version (10 ?)

Comment: Sequences have been around since version 6! See http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Sequence

Comment: Thanks for this very relevant information. It renders moot my second question ("What is keeping Oracle from implementing it?"), but my first question remains: "What is so superior and flexible about sequences + triggers that Oracle has not implemented IDENTITY until now?"

Comment: Firstly, a sequence is more flexible because you can use it for multiple purposes - not just for setting a column in a single table. Secondly, they're more flexible in that you can choose whether a row should use the sequence or not - you don't need to use a trigger if you don't want to.

Comment: The answer to the question "why didn't Oracle implement it until now" is simply that it's never been a priority, since the existing tools are more than adequate for the job at hand. The IDENTITY column is basically syntactic sugar for a sequence + column default anyway - with the addition of restricting the ability of applications to set the column to arbitrary values.